# An amusement park in space

Tags: physics, worldbuilding-process, microgravity

I am wondering what could make an amusement park better if it was in zero G? the people that will visit are already used to living in zero gravity, so something that would amuse us earthlings for them it is an everyday struggle, the novelty of zero gravity would mean nothing to them.

I am wondering if the physics of our roller coasters and vomit-inducing spinning rides could be bettered in a zero G setting to make new and more exhilarating rides?

Could any of our types of rides be changed to be more enjoyable, taking advantage of zero G, or are there any new rides that could be achieved in zero G that thrill seekers that had lived their whole life in zero gravity would enjoy?

Comment: Interesting idea, but too broad and opinion based. Please ask a question that can have a discernible right answer.

Comment: @kleer001 what do you feel is too broad? I don't feel this is opinion based as the science dictates what is possible?

Comment: "More enjoyable" is definitely opinion-based, for what it's worth.

Comment: Basically, everything you need to know is [here in this article.](http://www.spacefuture.com/archive/zero_gravity_sports_centers.shtml)

Comment: @jdunlop Not necessarily. The OP isn't asking "what ride would YOU enjoy", they're asking "how could amusement parks be improved given these gravity constraints". I think "enjoyability" for an amusement park can be defined clearly in terms of "provides a thrill through use of forces" so I don't think this is opinion-based.

Comment: @RandySavage If you're asking what is possible, then you'll need to edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, but anyway: https://what-if.xkcd.com/124/

Comment: I'm assuming you have already accounted for the negative affects of null G on the body... Someone raised in null G would develop very little comparable bone and muscle density and G forces would be incredibly painful unless the issue was supplemented.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle The characters will spend most of their time in rotating habitats but still have spent enough time in zero G that it isn't a novelty, so hopefully their body wont be frail or any other problem from the spinning habitats artificial G.

Comment: @RandySavage Then g-forces aren't really something that would entertain them most likely as they would be used to not only 1 g and null g, but regular shifts in g-force when transitioning between them, as well as likely higher g-forces from space craft travel. Their perspective on g-forces would probably be comparable to someone who skydives professionally, a regular Saturday afternoon...

Answer (score 3):

## [The Gravitron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitron)

People on earth are thrilled by freefall.  People in freefall would therefore be interested in the novelty of higher-than-normal-G.  Now, granted, you'd have to spin more gently than here on earth if they've lived in freefall all their lives, because they would be extremely frail, but the sensation of being pushed against the wall hard enough to pin them there would definitely be a novelty.

Similarly, rides that combined rapid acceleration/deceleration and video/3D projection could replicate any number of experiences that wouldn't ordinarily be available to your average citizen, whether a thrilling [space voyage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission:_Space), a fantasy adventure with [dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Escape_from_Gringotts), or some sort of [voyage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Voyage) into the body.

Zero-G wouldn't really facilitate the construction of any of these rides, since the rides most challenging to engineer due to gravity tend to *employ* that gravity (roller coasters, drop rides, etc.), and so wouldn't benefit from its removal.  It *would* make the limits to the rides you do construct much more stringent, as detailed above, as your freefall-acclimated humans would be much more fragile than their earth cousins.

Comment: As OP has now indicated in comments that they normally live in rotating habitats, the gravitron is basically their everyday life. Made sense before that comment though.

Answer (score 2):

### Unpredictability, Perceived Danger and Social aspects would still be there. This is why Amusement Parks exist.

If you look at amusement parks today, they are actually places that 'accentuate' emotional experiences. Loud, bright colours, music, food, and rides all combine to create a social place that most people (mainly younger) love.

When looking at the rides themselves they mostly have the following attributes:

- **Unpredictability**: part of the great experience of riding a roller coaster is the sudden changes of direction, the loop, and the surprise sometimes of doing it backwards unexpectingly. This is part of the thrill, and there is no reason to believe it would be any different in space.
- **Perceived Danger**: We all remember those moments when we 'think we're going to die'. Although (mostly) safe, amusement park rides put our bodies in perceived danger such that the thrill is overcoming the danger. This is of course applicable in zero gravity environments, but can also be replicated in space (quite easily). Imagine being on a roller coaster and almost hitting a series of free floating asteroids, or pretending a 'blow out' into space.
- **Social Aspects**: All of the above is the catalyst, but in real life people go to these places to have a good time with each other. It could be a date where couples go to have fun, or friends who want to just 'go somewhere' that is not an 'everyday life' place. Your amusement park is a welcome break from the likely monotony and possible social boredom of space travel.

These attributes are independent of setting, so you could literally have any 'theme' you want, but if you go to any Park today you notice that they are all trying to do these same things.

Zero gravity rides should be combined with food, sound and colour. They need to have danger and need to be unexpected. Perhaps the thrill of going through a rocket engine combined with the danger of it turning on, or a ride that goes through zero-g water blobs, some unexpectedly slimy some tasty, or simply a ride that takes unexpected dodges and turns, all combined with tasty food.